# What is another phrases for "My body is lean toward ..."?

Tags: phrase-request

What is another concise phrases for

> My body is **lean toward** the steering wheel to dodge the bullet

with the same meaning?

**lean toward** is the big part that need to revise.

It is difficult look up synonym phrases on all types of search engines.

Comment: **Formal** in what sense?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It mean concise yet not slang.

Comment: You can say *I leaned towards the steering wheel to avoid the bullet.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your phrase

> **leaned towards**

you could also use

> **leaned against**  *(using the steering wheel as support)*
>   **leaned forward** *(since the steering wheel is in front of you)*